# Jenkins SVN checkout ownership

Tags: android, svn, jenkins, gradle, permissions

I am checking out SVN repository to Jenkins workspace.
Here is the checked out repository directories

[image: Jenkin workspace]

If you look at the below image, the hidden directory (.gradle) and it's subdirectories is having root as an owner which is failing the Jenkins build.

[image: Workspace with some hidden files]

Error:

> .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock (Permission denied)

Since .gradle folder doesn't have permission for jenkins user.
SVN Jenkin Plugin version (2.5.7)

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

This is why you checkout your project with the correct user (jenkins) and you run jenkins build with root user.
You can resolve running jenkins under jenkins user, or you have to checkout your project with root user.

Try like in this post: [Run jenkins under different user](http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html)